# Boostrap chef client in an air gapped environment

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am setting up an instance using the chef server.
The instance is an air-gapped environment(not connected to the internet).
As a result of which it is attempting to download chef-client-latest.msi from
https://www.chef.io/chef/download/.

So it is throwing the error "Unable to connect to the remote server".

Can anyone suggest to me how to redirect this download instead of chef.io to any internal system within the systems reach?

The command I am using for bootstrap is
knife bootstrap winrm -U "username" -P "password"

Comment: The `knife bootstrap` command can be passed an `--msi-url` that is accessible to the node to skip downloading from chef.io.

Answer (score 0):

The knife bootstrap command can be passed an --msi-url that is accessible to the node to skip downloading from chef.io
Ref : https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_bootstrap/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).